Withdrawal BYBIT API
I'm trying to withdraw funds from my wallet via the BYBIT API, but it ends with an error:
{
  rateLimitApi: undefined,
  retCode: 131002,
  retMsg: 'Withdraw address chain or destination tag are not equal',
  result: {},
  retExtInfo: {},
  time: 1730925459032
}

Mine code:
const { RestClientV5 } = require('bybit-api');

const client = new RestClientV5({
  testnet: false,
  key: 'api_key', // stub, for example
  secret: 'secret_key', // stub, for example
});

client
  .submitWithdrawal({
    coin: 'USDT',
    chain: 'ETH',
    address: '0xfa3c24a644b03d20833866f59c539ec4794891ab',
    amount: '10',
    timestamp: Date.now(),
    forceChain: 0,
    accountType: 'FUND', // FUND, UNIFIED
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });

Here is an example from the documentation:
Documentation: https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/v5/asset/withdraw
const { RestClientV5 } = require('bybit-api');

const client = new RestClientV5({
  testnet: true,
  key: 'apikey',
  secret: 'apisecret',
});

client
  .submitWithdrawal({
    coin: 'USDT',
    chain: 'ETH',
    address: '0x99ced129603abc771c0dabe935c326ff6c86645d',
    amount: '24',
    timestamp: 1672196561407,
    forceChain: 0,
    accountType: 'FUND',
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });

Response example (from docs):
{
    "retCode": 0,
    "retMsg": "success",
    "result": {
        "id": "10195"
    },
    "retExtInfo": {},
    "time": 1672196571239
}

How can this problem be solved?
I tried changing networks: TON, TRX, but still the same error...

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems like you didn't include the tag parameter, which is required if a tag exists in the wallet address list. Could you please provide the exact wallet 's name.
